# debug in openerp6.1

Tags: odoo

I have added the following code in sale.py but I am unable to see output of print in
server.log. I wish to fill a one2many field by returned list of this function

### I am using openerp6.1 under windows xp

### my code is

```
 def model_id_change(self,cr,uid,ids,model_id,context=None):

        list1=[]

        if context is None:

            context = {}

        print "Hi"

        print str(model_id)

        if not model_id:

            raise osv.except_osv(_('No Model Selected !'),_('You have to select Model.'))

        querystr = 'SELECT microswitch FROM product_model WHERE id = ' + model_id

        print querystr

        try:

            cr.execute(querystr)

            s=cr.fetchone()

            print s

            list1=[]
            print list1

            for t in s.split(','):

                if t:

                    list1.append(t)

        except:

            exceptionType, exceptionValue, exceptionTraceback = sys.exc_info()

        return(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The print statement prints to standard output. If you want to get something in the server log, use the logging module.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('my message, with a substituted variable %s', s)
```